# Transparent effect is not working in \tcbhighmath

Tags: beamer

Transparent effect is not working in \tcbhighmath

MWE

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\newcommand\myRed[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{-1mm}\textcolor{red}{#1}}}

\tcbset{
common/.style={
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  left=1pt,
  right=1pt,
  top=1pt,
  bottom=1pt
  },
blue/.style={
  common,
  colback=LightBlue!90,
  colframe=LightBlue!90,
  highlight math style={colback=LightBlue!50,colframe=Navy,boxsep=0pt}
  },
green/.style={
  common,
  colback=Green!20,
  colframe=Green!20,
  highlight math style={colback=Green!20,colframe=Green}
  },
pink/.style={
  common,
  colback=red!10,
  colframe=red!10,
  highlight math style={colback=Green!20,colframe=Green}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Transparent effect}
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &= \frac{x}{y}\\
\uncover<2->{&= \frac{x}{y} \times {\frac{4}{4}}}\\
\uncover<3->{&= {\frac{4x}{4y}}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Transparent effect is not working}
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &= \frac{x}{y}\\
\uncover<2->{&= \frac{x}{y} \times \tcbhighmath[green]{\frac{4}{4}}}\\
\uncover<3->{&= \tcbhighmath[green]{\frac{4x}{4y}}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\newcommand\myRed[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{-1mm}\textcolor{red}{#1}}}

\tcbset{
common/.style={
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  left=1pt,
  right=1pt,
  top=1pt,
  bottom=1pt
  },
blue/.style={
  common,
  colback=LightBlue!90,
  colframe=LightBlue!90,
  highlight math style={colback=LightBlue!50,colframe=Navy,boxsep=0pt}
  },
green/.style={
  common,
  colback=Green!20,
  colframe=Green!20,
  highlight math style={colback=Green!20,colframe=Green}
  },
pink/.style={
  common,
  colback=red!10,
  colframe=red!10,
  highlight math style={colback=Green!20,colframe=Green}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Transparent effect}
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &= \frac{x}{y}\\
\uncover<2->{&= \frac{x}{y} \times {\frac{4}{4}}}\\
\uncover<3->{&= {\frac{4x}{4y}}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Transparent effect is now working}
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &= \frac{x}{y}\\
\uncover<2->{&= \frac{x}{y} \times \tcbhighmath[green]{\uncover<2->{\frac{4}{4}}}}\\
\uncover<3->{&= \tcbhighmath[green]{\uncover<3->{\frac{4x}{4y}}}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \frametitle{Transparent effect is now working}

Comment: @sandu :) :) :)

Comment: is it possible to remove green box in 4/4 term, when we uncover the next line?

Comment: @sandu Possible yes, but maybe it would be easier to use this approach https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291818/indentation-issues-with-highlighting-cell-using-tikzmarkin as it is overlay aware